# Extract Dates, Persons and Locations from Latin and English text

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have some text that I have been playing around where on top I have a summary in English of the contents in Latin. I am trying to perform NER on both texts to extract Dates, Locations and Persons. I started with the English portion thinking it should be easier and used chunking. The dates are not being recognized and not all entities are being caught. Is there a way to customize the output to make it more accurate. 
Here is an example of my code:

```
text = 'Thursday, 3 September 1467. The Jew Azar Nifusi leases his fields called Ta Xellula and Gnien Hagem in the district of Dejr is-Safsaf for ten years to Nicolaus Delia and his son Lemus for the price of eight salme of wheat each harvest-time. The tenants also bind themselves to give Nifusi each year ten salme of brushwood and two salme of straw. On his part the Jew promised to build a surrounding wall for the fields at his own expense.'
import nltk 
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary = True)

entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:
    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))
print set(entity_names)
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
set(['Nicolaus Delia', 'Gnien Hagem', 'Dejr', 'Nifusi', 'Jew'])
```

I was expecting the date, Jew, Azar Nifusi, Ta Xellula, Gnien Hagem, Dejr is-Safsaf, Nicolaus Delia and Lemus to be extracted at least. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Using this line of code gives me things like date and all that as well. It's in a tree format, but I am assuming you can extract the things in a cleaner format later by yourself.

```
ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
```

Output:

```
Tree('S', [('Thursday', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('3', 'CD'), ('September', 'NNP'), ('1467', 'CD'), ('.', '.'), ('The', 'DT'), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Jew', 'NNP'), ('Azar', 'NNP'), ('Nifusi', 'NNP')]), ('leases', 'VBZ'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('fields', 'NNS'), ('called', 'VBD'), Tree('PERSON', [('Ta', 'NNP'), ('Xellula', 'NNP')]), ('and', 'CC'), Tree('PERSON', [('Gnien', 'NNP'), ('Hagem', 'NNP')]), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('district', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), Tree('GPE', [('Dejr', 'NNP')]), ('is-Safsaf', 'NN'), ('for', 'IN'), ('ten', 'JJ'), ('years', 'NNS'), ('to', 'TO'), Tree('PERSON', [('Nicolaus', 'NNP'), ('Delia', 'NNP')]), ('and', 'CC'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('son', 'NN'), Tree('PERSON', [('Lemus', 'NNP')]), ('for', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('price', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('eight', 'CD'), ('salme', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), ('wheat', 'NN'), ('each', 'DT'), ('harvest-time', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('The', 'DT'), ('tenants', 'NNS'), ('also', 'RB'), ('bind', 'VBP'), ('themselves', 'PRP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('give', 'VB'), Tree('PERSON', [('Nifusi', 'NNP')]), ('each', 'DT'), ('year', 'NN'), ('ten', 'RB'), ('salme', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('brushwood', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('two', 'CD'), ('salme', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('straw', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('On', 'IN'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('part', 'NN'), ('the', 'DT'), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Jew', 'NNP')]), ('promised', 'VBD'), ('to', 'TO'), ('build', 'VB'), ('a', 'DT'), ('surrounding', 'VBG'), ('wall', 'NN'), ('for', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('fields', 'NNS'), ('at', 'IN'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('own', 'JJ'), ('expense', 'NN'), ('.', '.')])
```

Comment: Isn't a tree created per sentence in this case? I tried to use IOB tags as well as per this tutorial https://nlpforhackers.io/named-entity-extraction/ but the results are very weak

Comment: Yes, a tree is created. However, you can always extract the info you want out of the tree. What do you mean the results are weak?

Comment: For example: Jew Azar Nifusi should be Azar Nifusi only as that is a name and surname not an organization. Or Ta' Xellula is a location not a person. How would you clean such a tree and make it more accurate?

Comment: Have you considered using SpaCy? I usually use that for NER. I posted the result in NLTK here because your question was related to NLTK. For my thesis, I used SpaCy and was fairly happy with the results.

Comment: Not yet...I will give it a go maybe it will give me better results then. I thought I was doing something wrong! Thanks for being helpful

Comment: I hope SpaCy gives you better results then. Good luck.